Proof of the uniqueness of the Jordan Measure
I am trying to do the following exercise from Terence Tao's Measure Theory book:
Let $m' : J(\mathbf{R}^d) \to \mathbf{R}^+$ be a map from the collection $J(\mathbf{R}^d)$ of Jordan measurable subsets of $\mathbf{R}^d$ to non-negative reals that obeys non-negativity, finite additivity and translation invariance properties. Show that there exists a constant $c \in \mathbf{R}^+$ such that for all Jordan measurable sets $E$ we have $m'(E) = c m(E)$
The main idea of what I was trying to write is to take any Jordan measurable set, partition it to identical boxes according to a certain 'ruler', show that those boxes were also Jordan measurable, and later on find the relationship between the measure given by the ruler I used and a measure I would have if I were to use another ruler.
My attempt at formalizing this is as following:
Let $m' : E \in J(\mathbf{R}^d) \to \mathbf{R}^+$ be a mapping
Let $E = \bigcup^N_i B_i$ where $B_i = [x_i , x_{i+1}[$
$E$ is Jordan measurable, therefore, $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\underline{E} \subset E \subset \overline{E}$ such that $m'(\overline{E}) - m'(\underline{E}) < \epsilon$
so, we have $m'(\bigcup^N_i\overline{B_i}) - m'(\bigcup^N_i\underline{B_i}) < \epsilon$
As E was partitioned into identical boxes, $m'(E) = N m'(B_i)$ and idem for the inner and outer covers:
$N \sum^N m'(\overline{B_i}) -N \sum^N m'(\underline{B_i})  < \epsilon $
factorizing, we get
$N [\sum^N m'(\overline{B_i}) -\sum^N m'(\underline{B_i})]  < \epsilon $
and so,
$\sum^N m'(\overline{B_i}) -\sum^N m'(\underline{B_i})]  < \epsilon $
Now I change the measure, let $m : J(\mathbf{R}^d) \to \mathbf{R}^+$
I measure the same boxes with a different measure:
$m(E) = m(\bigcup^M B_i)$ = \sum^M (B_i) = M m(B_i)$
So I have: $m'(E) = N m'(B_i)$ and $m(E) = M m(B_i)$
Dividing them, I get:
$\frac{m'(E)}{m(E) }= \frac{N m'(B_i)}{M m(B_i)}$ where $m(B_i) = \frac{m(E)}{M}$ and so
$\frac{m'(E)}{m(E) } = \frac{N}{M^2}$
where I call $\frac{N}{M^2} = c \in \mathbf{R}^+$ as $N,M \in \mathbf{R}^+$
Is this idea and the proof okay? How can I improve them? I find my passage from $\underline{E} \subset E \subset \overline{E}$ to $\underline{B_i} \subset B_i \subset \overline{B_i}$ a bit questionable, do I miss any arguments?

How did you get your first assertion about $m'$??? ("$E$ is Jordan measureable ... thererfore...".)

I tried to apply the definition of $E$ being Jordan measurable; the inner measure of $E$ and outer measure of $E$ should be equal to each other. I assigned $m'(\underline{E})$
to be the inner measure and $m'(\overline{E})$ to be the outer measure so for any $\epsilon > 0$ I should have $m'(\overline{E}) - m'(\underline{E}) < \epsilon$
